# Most Efficient/Pythonic Way to Do Calculations on a Specific Subset of a 2D Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So here is a breakdown of the task:

1) I have a 197x10 2D numpy array. I scan through this and identify specific cells that are of interest (criteria that goes into choosing these cells is not important.) These cells are not restricted to one specific area of the matrix.

2) I have 3247 other 2D Numpy arrays with the same dimension. For a single one of these other arrays, I need to take the cell locations of interest specified by step 1) and take the average of all of these (sum them all together and divide by the number of cell locations of interest.)

3) I need to repeat 2) for each of the other 3246 remaining arrays.

What is the best/most efficient way to "mark" the cells of interest and look at them quickly in the 3247 arrays?

**--sample on smaller set--**

Let's say given a 2x2 array:

[1, 2]
[3, 4]

Perhaps the cells of interest are the ones that contain 1 and 4. Therefore, for the following arrays:

[5, 6]
[7, 8]

and

[9, 10]
[11, 12]

I would want to take (5+8)/2 and record that somewhere.
I would also want to take (9+12)/2 and record that somewhere.

**EDIT**

Now if I wanted to find these cells of interest in a pythonic way (using Numpy) with the following criteria:

-start at the first row and check the first element
-continue to go down rows in that column marking elements that satisfy condition
-Stop on the first element that does not satisfy the condition and then go to the next column.

So basically now I want to just keep the row-wise (for a specific column) contiguous cells that are of interest. So for 1), if the array looks like:

```
[1 2 3]  
[4 5 6]  
[7 8 9]
```

And 1,4, 2, 8, and 3 were of interest, I'd only mark 1, 4, 2, 3, since 5 disqualifies 8 as being included.

Comment: Find some way (code) that does what you intend to do then find the bottleneck and then try to optimize it.

Comment: Are the locations of those specific cells the same across all those 3247 arrays? Also, instead of having 3247 such arrays, can you setup a 3D array to store all that data, such that we would have a single array of shape `(3247,197,10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonic way:

```
answers = []
# this generates index matrix where the condition is met.
idx = np.argwhere( your condition of (1) matrix comes here)

for array2d in your_3247_arrays:
    answer = array2d[idx].mean()
    answers.append()
print(answers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(197, 10)
B = np.random.rand(3247, 197, 10)

loc = np.where(A > 0.9)

B[:, loc[0], loc[1]].mean(axis=1)
```